# mongodb find exact document

Tags: mongodb, find, pull

Im looking for a way in MongoDB to find an exact document, meaning that I dont want to match document with other fields than the ones expected.

This is what I can do on subdocuments

```
> db.test.insert({a:{b:1,c:2}});
> db.test.insert({a:{b:1}});
> db.test.find({'a.b':1}); // non exact match
{a:{b:1,c:2}}
{a:{b:1}}
> db.test.find({'a':{'b':1}}); // exact match
{a:{b:1}}
```

I'd like to do the same on the main document (not a subdocument). But

```
> db.test.insert({b:1,c:2});
> db.test.insert({b:1});
> db.test.find({'b':1}); // non exact match
{a:{b:1,c:2}}
{a:{b:1}}
> db.test.find({'.':{'b':1}}); // does not work :(
> db.test.find({'b':1, 'c':null}); // works, but how I am supposed to know that 'c' could exists ???
{a:{b:1}}
```

The final goal being to do this with `$pull` on arrays

```
> db.test.insert({a:[{b:1,c:2},{b:1,d:3},{b:1,c:2},{b:1,c:2,d:3}]});
> db.test.update({}, {$pull:{'a':{b:1,c:2}}});
> db.test.find();
{a:[{b:1,d:3}]} // NOOOO :'(
```

Has anybody an idea about it ?

edit :

Here are some precision on exact / partial matching I found on arrays :

- array item exact matching : `db.test.find({'a':{b:1,c:2}});`
- array item partial matching : `db.test.find({'a':{$elemMatch:{b:1,c:2}}});`
- array item removal partial matching : `db.test.update({}, {$pull:{'a':{b:1,c:2}}})`
- array item removal exact matching : `db.test.update({}, {$pullAll:{'a':[{b:1,c:2}]}})` (thanks to JohnnyHK)

Comment: Would you please rename this question to "mongodb remove document from array that is an exact match" or something like that?  I was looking for an answer to your initial question and was disappointed to find the actual question had to do with arrays.  Thank you!  FYI to folks who come here looking for answers to the initial question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993275/how-to-exact-match-entire-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not well documented, but if you use [`$pullAll`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/#up._S_pullAll) instead of `$pull`, only the exactly matching elements are removed:

```js
db.test.update({}, {$pullAll:{a: [{b:1,c:2}]}});
```

Comment: Wow youre right ! Strange behavior ... but thank you