# How to exact match entire document?

Tags: mongodb

Exact matching subdocuments is easy, but is there a way to exact match entire document in a collection ?

I have a lot of documents with similar data, and I only need exact matches with no extra data

Using negative $exists will not work for me, as I dont know all the possible fields beforehand.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "exact match" a sub document? How do you think you that without knowing all the possible fields there? This sounds like mixing terms to me an is very unclear.

Comment: well if I'm looking for a document {a:5} I don't want it to match {a:5, b:1}, only {a:5}

Comment: You misread my example. I said that if I query {a:1} I want ONLY the documents that are EXACTLY {a:1} and NOT ones like {a:1, b:1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think this is possible outright, but a possible solution is to hash the document.

when saving, always create a hash of the document:

```
var doc = {};
delete doc.hash; // never include the hash itself in the calculation
doc.hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(JSON.stringify(doc)).digest();
db.collection.insert(doc);
```

Then when querying, you can query by hash:

```
db.collection.find({
  hash: hash
})
```

might be annoying if you frequently do atomic updates on the document.

Comment: That kind of sucks, especially since you can exact match subdocuments

Comment: An elegant solution to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal way, but really the only way to filter this out on the server is using JavaScript evaluation of the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator. Make sure it's used with a traditional query though to at least get some performance benefit from index selection as the JavaScript by itself cannot do that.

Consider the following:

```js
{ "a" : 1 }
{ "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
{ "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }
{ "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3, "d" : 4 }
```

So now you need to match the "third" document only. Here's the basic code concept:

```js
var query = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 };
var string =  "";

Object.keys(query).forEach(function(key) {
    if (query[key].constructor.toString().match(/(Array|Object)/) == null) 
        string += key + query[key].valueOf().toString();
});

query['$where'] = 'function() { ' +
    'var compare =  ""; ' +
    'var string = "' + string + '"; ' +

    'var doc = this; ' +
    'delete doc._id; ' +

    'Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(key) { ' +
        'if (doc[key].contructor.toString().match(/(Array|Object)/) == null) ||' +
          'compare += key + doc[key].valueOf().toString(); ' +
    '}); ' +
    'return compare == string; ' +
'};';

db.test.find(query);
```

Some drivers have better concepts for intermixing an external variable into code but it gives the basic idea.

You need to compute an external picture or hash from the required exact fields and values and then use the same method on the server to compute that from the current document fields. Naturally `_id` is always excluded because it is unique.

You don't need the signature for sub-elements because as you said you can "exact match" those purely in the query. So it's just a matter of excluding those from the comparison generation.

The general query arguments will do most of the work, and in this case narrow that down to two documents, ideally using an index to do so. The rest of the matching is done by "brute force" JavaScript evaluation, so that only the documents with the matching signature to the fields in your query.

Answer (score -1):

I really don't understand your question, can you explain it ?

If you want documents that doesnt have some fields you can use **$exists**.

For example, if you have...

```
{a: 1 , b: "1", c: true }
{a: 2, b: "2", c: false}
{a: null, b: "3" }
```

Then `db.my_collection.find({a: {$exists: true}});` finds

```
{a: 1 , b: "1", c: true }
{a: 2, b: "2", c: false}
```

And `db.my_collection.find({a: {$exists: false}});` finds

```
{a: null, b: "3" }
```

Comment: I cant rely on $exists as there are too many possible fields.